# Multiple dex files error when building project downloaded from git

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, ant

So I have a project that works totally fine in one workspace on my machine. I push it to the repository so everyone else can work on it. I go to pull it down making sure all the changes are good. I import the project into a new workspace and using eclipse with autobuild on it produces no errors.

I go to the command line and run ant clean release on the project and right before it gets to run crunch on the assets the build fails with a mulitple dex files define error. Ive checked the project high and low and compared to the other copy of it in the original workspace but for what ever reason I cant get it to build. I erase the bin and gen folders and remove all the imports and basically leave just the project, run clean in eclipse, and still get a dex define error related to one of the lib projects classes. Ive tried to find where extra copies could be but I dont find anything.

googling around for the past few days hasnt helped as the normal solutions to such a problem havent worked for me. So what is the best way to figure out where the extra class definitions are coming from so I can get rid of them and fix the repository so I can use it correctly. I have a feeling its related to one of the files in the project that I should be excluding in my gitignore but Im not sure which that would be. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated cause this has eaten quite a bit of time of just messing around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt find the root of the problem but I figured out a fix. I moved all the support libraries to a new root folder completely away from the android project. Once I did that and cleaned everything I then ran ant clean release and the project built fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one class with the same package name this error would raise.
One of the common source of this issue is when you have for example different version on the same library.
For example your add `ActionbarSherlock` which in `'libs` forder has it's own `support library` and also your project has another version of `support library` in it's `libs` folder. In such a cases you should put one version of `support library`.jar to all different libraries that you using it.
I hope this could help you.

Comment: Unfortunately this isnt related to a jar which wouldve been an easy fix. It has to do with a certain class that is in a project that my android project is dependent on and for some reason gets added twice. Ive tried locating the duplicate file but I just cant find it. Ive even tried letting everything build into another folder outside the project instead of the bin file but still its a no go.